# Problems with a git repo in Sharepoint documents library shared as drive

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, mapped-folder

My team is trialling the use of Sharepoint Online and Teams to replace a public network drive for our docs and work files. I'm running into a problem when trying to use git: creating the repo with `git init` works, but adding and committing files fails with an error:

```
fatal: cannot use .git/info/exclude as an exclude file
```

The repo in question is a very simple one, just 4 small files in a directory a couple of levels down from the root.

Are there known problems with using git on a shared document library, mapped as a network drive? I had a look at the [list of limitations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us), and it doesn't seem like there should be problems.

At a previous job I had git repos in my OneDrive for Business, and it mostly worked fine (although I ran into intermittent sync glitches).

Comment: The `.git` directory does seem to be created correctly; I can see it both in Explorer and in the SPO docs library in the browser. The `.git/info/exclude` file is there as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Azure DevOps or GitHub to host your repositories rather than a SharePoint document library. [Microsoft recommend syncing SharePoint document libraries using the OneDrive for Business application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53) rather than mapping a library to a network drive.

Comment: The use case is not that people are hosting repos in Sharepoint, but rather cloning them from Github/ADO/etc. In any case, it looks like using OD for Business is the better route

Answer (score 0):

1.Add your SharePoint as windows drive in ms dos command prompt using below command.

net use z: https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/xxx

2.Navigate to z drive and create a repo folder.

cd z:

makedir proj1

3.Create git repo

git init --bare

4.Navigate to local folder.

cd ”c:\repo"

5.Clone SharePoint repo in local folder.

git clone file://z:\proj1

Comment: A bare metal repo shouldn't be available for usage from within a SharePoint document library.